# fail reading whatsapp backup files

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Kindly help,how do i read or retrieve watsup backup files stored in database folder. Everytime when im opening a file it says 'no application can support this action"

Answer (score 0):

This feature availabe only with WhatsApp for `Backup and Restore`.

(only whatsapp can Open and use it)

for backup and restore, follow below link.

**WhatsApp FAQ :**
[**How to save and restore chat history backups**](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/s60/23245511)